# Sorting through shell, awk, bash?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to learn bash/shell *nix commands /scripting.
So rather than writing a python program, I thought of trying it out using bash/awk etc but am having a hard time.
I have a huge text (its actually csv )file

```
 id_1, id_2, some attributes.
```

I want to sort this file based on id2?
how do i do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `--key` option for `sort`.

For example, the following sorts `input.csv` on the second field (using comma as a field separator) and writes the output to `output.csv`.

```
 sort --key=2,2 -t',' input.csv > output.csv
```

p.s. Don't forget to use the `-n` option if you're doing a numerical sort.

For more info, see the [man page for sort](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort).

Comment: I hate when people are pedantic like this but I am going to be pedantic like this:  You don't need cat here as sort takes the file name as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **-k** option of *sort(1)*

> -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
>
> ```
>          start a key at POS1, end it at POS2 (origin 1)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
sort -t, -k2 filename.csv
```

I don't have a shell to verify, but basically you need to specify the separator and the sort key

Comment: `-k2,2` to sort only on the second field, not the second through last field.

Answer (score 1):

checkout the command cut:

```
cat file.cvs | cut -d";" -f 2 | sort
```

I assumed your csv is semi-colon separated, but you can change it.

Save into a different name:

```
cat file.cvs | cut -d";" -f 2 | sort > newfile.txt
```

Comment: Hi, Can I save this result under a different file name ??

Comment: @Fraz, I posted above an update. But I must admit, I misunderstood you. You wanted to sort the file, I answered how to sort only the second field.